# Why are tests taking longer to run in TeamCity than when run directly in NUnit?

Tags: c#, performance, nunit, teamcity

I have some C# performance tests, basically running two different methods and checking that one runs much faster than the other.

When I run them locally in NUnit, one of the tests runs ten times as fast as the other, so I've got an NUnit test that uses `Stopwatch` to check that it is at least twice as fast (in case of regression). But when I run the tests in TeamCity, the fast method is only about 1.5 times as fast as the slow one? I would expect hardware differences to have some effect, but not this much. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer my own question, the problem turned out to be that code coverage was turned on for the test build in TeamCity, so the overhead of this brought the two method runtimes closer together. Hopefully this answer helps someone else in future.

Comment: I actually don't see code coverage turned on, and it still takes almost an hour to run my tests on the build server, whereas it takes roughly 7-8 minutes locally.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you running the same type (i.e. Debug not Release) on both? Also looking at the durations of the tests on the build server -- are they all slower equally, or is one of them a lot slower?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Many of them are actually a lot slower, not just one, unfortunately.  They are making DB calls, but that shouldn't really matter, should it?I believe I'm running in Debug in both.

Comment: Various things it could be. Is the build server busy doing other things? Are the versions of nunit the same? Is the network between the build server and the database slow? Might be worth getting the artifacts from the build server and running them through your local NUnit to see if that sheds any light on the difference.