# 15 seconds delay when reading Configuration file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, configuration, teamcity, configuration-files

I have a strange problem when reading configuration file from unit test. My code:

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
string filePath = configuration.FilePath;
```

There is a 15 seconds delay when I try to execute this code from unit test from TeamCity on server. When I run this code from my local machine, it runs smoothly without any delays.

[Print Sceen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geCKs.png)

Any ideas where to look for a problem?

---

Edit

I was able to narrow the problem. Using process monitoring I was able to catch, that QTAgent32 is making some some weird requests to ip address 2.18.213.225:

[QTAgent32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLtF3.png)

Message analyzer is showing, that this is in fact domain a1363.dscg.akamai.net. Is there a way to disable this?

---

Solution

The problem was in the proxy configuration on server. Once we reconfigured it properly, the problem was gone.

Comment: Maybe something to do with code coverage being turned on? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884168/why-are-tests-taking-longer-to-run-in-teamcity-than-when-run-directly-in-nunit

Comment: Did your computers have joined in a `active directory domain`?

Comment: @Fuzzybear No, we don't have code coverage turn on.

Comment: @Ali Yes, server and local machine are in the same AD domain.

Comment: and it takes **15 seconds** every single time? If yes I think I know what's wrong with it. It's related to the `DNS Server`. Make sure you can ping your full computer-names (eg: myPc.domain.com) on both computers. ( eg: you should be able to ping a from b and vise-versa ) and TeamCity servers should be able to active directory domain.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad Thanks Ali. I was able to narrow the problem. I edited my original post.